# Python Pandas Cumprod issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am still struggling with the following code:

```
xa= [0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 67, 69, 75, 0, 0, 0]
xb = [.3, .3, .3,.3, .3, .3, .3, .3, .3, .3, .3]
ideal = [0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 67, 69, 75, 67.5, 60.75, 54.675]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':xa, 'b':xb, 'i':ideal})

mask=(df['a']<51) & (df['b']>0)
df['c'] = df['a'].where(mask,0.9).groupby(~mask.cumsum()).cumprod()

print(df)
```

I want 'c' column to become like 'ideal'. This is just a sample of my 100K+ rows full dataset.

'mask' is calculated likes this:
When 'a'{i}<51 AND 'b'{i}>0 ? then TRUE else FALSE

'c' column is calculated like that:
When 'mask'{i}=FALSE then 'c'{i}='a'{i} else 'c'{i}=0.9*'c'{i-1}

So I hope (one day) 'c' to become like 'ideal'....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this solves your problem:

```
# First calculate the column as if there is no decay
mask=(df['a']<51) & (df['b']>0)
df['c'] = df['a'].where(~mask)
df['c'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df['c'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Check how many rows since the mask has changed from True to False or v.v.
df['ones'] = 1
df['power'] = df['ones'].groupby((mask != mask.shift()).cumsum()).transform('cumsum')
# For the values in the mask, apply the decay
df['c'] = np.where(mask, 0.9 ** df['power']*df['c'], df['c'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     a    b       i       c  power ones
0    0  0.3   0.000   0.000       1     1
1    0  0.3   0.000   0.000       2     1
2    0  0.3   0.000   0.000       3     1
3    0  0.3   0.000   0.000       4     1
4   65  0.3  65.000  65.000       1     1
5   67  0.3  67.000  67.000       2     1
6   69  0.3  69.000  69.000       3     1
7   75  0.3  75.000  75.000       4     1
8    0  0.3  67.500  67.500       1     1
9    0  0.3  60.750  60.750       2     1
10   0  0.3  54.675  54.675       3     1
```

The main trick is to define one column that defines how many times to multiply the 0.9 and another that is forward filled to check what the number would have been if there hadn't been a decay. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your logic is not data analysis oriented but it is common logic and math and actually works! I like your approach. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly

```
mask=(df['a']<51) & (df['b']>0)
df['c'] = np.where(mask, df['i'].shift() * 0.9, df['i'])
df.fillna(0, inlace = True)

    a   b   i       c
0   0   0.3 0.000   0.000
1   0   0.3 0.000   0.000
2   0   0.3 0.000   0.000
3   0   0.3 0.000   0.000
4   65  0.3 65.000  65.000
5   67  0.3 67.000  67.000
6   69  0.3 69.000  69.000
7   75  0.3 75.000  75.000
8   0   0.3 67.500  67.500
9   0   0.3 60.750  60.750
10  0   0.3 54.675  54.675
```

Comment: I do not want to use ideal or 'i'. I put it there just as a benchmark to show you the result I need; You can freely try 'a' and 'b' instead.